# Can I put a comma before as well?

Tags: grammar, commas

Can a comma be placed before as well?

> People aren’t just struggling with the snow near their homes, it’s affecting their daily travels *as well*.

Comment: +1 It's a shame that this question only has 4 upvotes and its answer 8 while it is a good question, is protected and has been viewed over 20,000 times. :(

Answer (score 16):

No: you should not place a comma before *as well* at the end of a sentence.

You would normally put a comma before *as* if it introduces a further explanation of the function of something, and only then if it is an afterthought: *he liked her, as a friend*. And of course you would use a comma if *as* introduces a full clause that is not closely connected to the main clause: *English is not difficult, as it is a Germanic language*. But, in other situations, you normally wouldn't put a comma before *as*.